# creation of a text file in a specified location and remove the old one

Tags: vbscript

I need to create a text file "setup.txt" in the location **C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\xerox\setapp** in VB script
the location **C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data** is common apllication data folder here we can
use word "**CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA" or &H23&** for that.Here the other which i need to take care is if any setup.txt file are
already there in that location **i need to remove that old one i need to insert the new "setup.txt" which contatin blank
values means new one**

I am new to this vbscript ,and i wanted an optimized code to acheive that functionality

Comment: any experts are there pls help me

Answer (score 1):

You could open the file for writing and write a blank line, this will create the new text file and overwrite any previous versions.

```
    strFilename = " C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\xerox\setapp.txt"
    Set objFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strFilename,2,true)
     'Write stuff to the file here
    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = nothing
```

It's not clear if your script is creating the log file, if not and you want to copy the file and overwrite any previous ones you could do this (setting the last argument in the CopyFile method to true will overwrite older versions).

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile Source, Destination, true
Set fso = Nothing
```

If you just want to delete the previous file if it exists you could do this (here setting the last argument in the DeleteFile method to true will force deletion of the file).

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(file) Then
     fso.DeleteFile file, true
End If
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, VBScript, it was a long time ago ... But I'll give it a shot.

What you need, if I understand you correctly, is to use the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(VS.85).aspx) it contains methods for [deleting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thx0f315(VS.85).aspx), [creating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(VS.85).aspx) and [copying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w(VS.85).aspx) text files.

I hope this at least gives you some pointers to get you started.